# erase functionality in android finger paint

Tags: android, paint

I doing finger paint on the image which contains as a background.After drawing some lines or arcs on the image i need erase functionality to erase the paint using finger touch.

I googled about this but i did not find any proper solution for it.I am developing for minimum android version 2.2

Here is my code i did so far.

```
public class DrawPanel extends View {

    private Paint p;
    private ArrayList<Point> points;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> strokes;
    private ArrayList<Paint> mVisiblePaints = new ArrayList<Paint>();
    int currentColor;
    boolean isDraw = true;



    public DrawPanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        strokes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>();
        currentColor = Color.RED;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        super.onDraw(c);
        int i = 0;
        for (ArrayList<Point> obj : strokes) {
            Paint paint = mVisiblePaints.get(i);
            drawStroke( obj, c, paint);
            i++;
        }
        if (p != null)
        drawStroke(points, c, p);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            p = createPaint(currentColor, 10);
            invalidate();
        }
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if (isDraw)
            {
            points.add(new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()));
            }
            else
            eraseScreen(new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()));
            invalidate();
        }

        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
        {
            this.strokes.add(points);
            points = new ArrayList<Point>();
            mVisiblePaints.add(p);
            invalidate();
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void drawStroke(ArrayList<Point> stroke, Canvas c, Paint paint) {
        if (stroke.size() > 0) {
            Point p0 = (Point) stroke.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < stroke.size(); i++) {
                Point p1 = (Point) stroke.get(i);
                c.drawLine(p0.x, p0.y, p1.x, p1.y, paint);
                p0 = p1;
            }
        }
    }

    private Paint createPaint(int color, float width) {
        Paint temp = new Paint();
        temp.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        temp.setDither(true);
        temp.setAntiAlias(true);
        temp.setColor(color);
        temp.setStrokeWidth(width);
        temp.setStrokeCap(Cap.ROUND);
        temp.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        return temp;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current drawing color.
     * 
     * @param color
     */
    public void setColor(int color) {
        currentColor = color;
    }

    public void setIsDraw(boolean isDraw) {
        this.isDraw = isDraw;
    }

    public boolean getIsDraw() {
        return isDraw;
    }

    public void eraseScreen(Point p)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<strokes.size();i++)
        {
            ArrayList<Point> listPoints=strokes.get(i);
            //ArrayList<Point> drawPoints=new ArrayList<Point>();
            if(listPoints.size()>0)
            {
            for(int j=0;j<listPoints.size();j++)
            {
                Point pp=listPoints.get(j);
                float dx = Math.abs(p.x - pp.x);
                float dy = Math.abs(p.y - pp.y);
                if(dx<=5 && dy<=5)
                {
                    listPoints.remove(j);
                }
            }
            strokes.add(i, listPoints);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest  solution for this, to achieve.

Comment: I have done it by changing `paint` color to `White`, you can try the same

Comment: but my background is not only a white color its an image with different colors

Comment: I think setting white color to paint won't effect images

Comment: its drawing with white color by overriding background image.But it should not override

Comment: @koti i can give you an alternative solution other than using the above code. i have a sample but it does not use arraylist. sample made using fingerpaint api

Comment: @Raghunandan Thank you can you share your sample code

Comment: @koti since you have asked for an alternative i have posted the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As op is asking for an alternative

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_drawing_pad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class FingerPaintActivity extends Activity implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {    

MyView mv;
AlertDialog dialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

mv= new MyView(this);
mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.afor);//set background here
setContentView(mv);
mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mPaint.setDither(true);
mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);

mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },
                           0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
}

private Paint       mPaint;
private MaskFilter  mEmboss;
private MaskFilter  mBlur;

public void colorChanged(int color) {
mPaint.setColor(color);
}

public class MyView extends View {

private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;
private Bitmap  mBitmap;
private Canvas  mCanvas;
private Path    mPath;
private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
Context context;

public MyView(Context c) {
super(c);
context=c;
mPath = new Path();
mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);   
}

@Override
 protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas);

canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
//showDialog(); 
mPath.reset();
mPath.moveTo(x, y);
mX = x;
mY = y;

}
private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
    mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}
}
private void touch_up() {
mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
// commit the path to our offscreen
mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
// kill this so we don't double draw
mPath.reset();
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN));
//mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
float x = event.getX();
float y = event.getY();

switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touch_start(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        touch_move(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        touch_up();
        invalidate();
        break;
}
return true;
}  
}

private static final int COLOR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int EMBOSS_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
private static final int BLUR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
private static final int ERASE_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
private static final int SRCATOP_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;
private static final int Save = Menu.FIRST + 5;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

menu.add(0, COLOR_MENU_ID, 0, "Color").setShortcut('3', 'c');
menu.add(0, EMBOSS_MENU_ID, 0, "Emboss").setShortcut('4', 's');
menu.add(0, BLUR_MENU_ID, 0, "Blur").setShortcut('5', 'z');
menu.add(0, ERASE_MENU_ID, 0, "Erase").setShortcut('5', 'z');
menu.add(0, SRCATOP_MENU_ID, 0, "SrcATop").setShortcut('5', 'z');
menu.add(0, Save, 0, "Save").setShortcut('5', 'z');

return true;
}

@Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
 return true;
 }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
mPaint.setXfermode(null);
mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);

switch (item.getItemId()) {
case COLOR_MENU_ID:
    new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
    return true;
case EMBOSS_MENU_ID:
    if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mEmboss) {
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
    } else {
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
    }
    return true;
case BLUR_MENU_ID:
    if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mBlur) {
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);
    } else {
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
    }
    return true;
case ERASE_MENU_ID:
    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                            PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    return true;
case SRCATOP_MENU_ID:

    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                        PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
    mPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
    return true;
case Save:
    AlertDialog.Builder editalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FingerPaintActivity.this);
        editalert.setTitle("Please Enter the name with which you want to Save");
        final EditText input = new EditText(FingerPaintActivity.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        input.setLayoutParams(lp);
        editalert.setView(input);
        editalert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            String name= input.getText().toString();
            Bitmap bitmap = mv.getDrawingCache();

         String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); 
            File file = new File("/sdcard/"+name+".png");           
            try 
            {
                if(!file.exists())
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);

                ostream.close();
                mv.invalidate();                            
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally
            {

                mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);                           
            }
            }
        });

        editalert.show();       
    return true;    
 }
 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

ColorPicker

```
public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog {

public interface OnColorChangedListener {
    void colorChanged(int color);
}

private OnColorChangedListener mListener;
private int mInitialColor;

private static class ColorPickerView extends View {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mCenterPaint;
    private final int[] mColors;
    private OnColorChangedListener mListener;

    ColorPickerView(Context c, OnColorChangedListener l, int color) {
        super(c);
        mListener = l;
        mColors = new int[] {
            0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00,
            0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFF0000
        };
        Shader s = new SweepGradient(0, 0, mColors, null);

        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setShader(s);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(32);

        mCenterPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mCenterPaint.setColor(color);
        mCenterPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }

    private boolean mTrackingCenter;
    private boolean mHighlightCenter;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float r = CENTER_X - mPaint.getStrokeWidth()*0.5f;

        canvas.translate(CENTER_X, CENTER_X);

        canvas.drawOval(new RectF(-r, -r, r, r), mPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, CENTER_RADIUS, mCenterPaint);

        if (mTrackingCenter) {
            int c = mCenterPaint.getColor();
            mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            if (mHighlightCenter) {
                mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
            } else {
                mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
            }
            canvas.drawCircle(0, 0,
                              CENTER_RADIUS + mCenterPaint.getStrokeWidth(),
                              mCenterPaint);

            mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mCenterPaint.setColor(c);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(CENTER_X*2, CENTER_Y*2);
    }

    private static final int CENTER_X = 100;
    private static final int CENTER_Y = 100;
    private static final int CENTER_RADIUS = 32;

    private int floatToByte(float x) {
        int n = java.lang.Math.round(x);
        return n;
    }
    private int pinToByte(int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            n = 0;
        } else if (n > 255) {
            n = 255;
        }
        return n;
    }

    private int ave(int s, int d, float p) {
        return s + java.lang.Math.round(p * (d - s));
    }

    private int interpColor(int colors[], float unit) {
        if (unit <= 0) {
            return colors[0];
        }
        if (unit >= 1) {
            return colors[colors.length - 1];
        }

        float p = unit * (colors.length - 1);
        int i = (int)p;
        p -= i;

        // now p is just the fractional part [0...1) and i is the index
        int c0 = colors[i];
        int c1 = colors[i+1];
        int a = ave(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), p);
        int r = ave(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), p);
        int g = ave(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), p);
        int b = ave(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), p);

        return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
    }

    private int rotateColor(int color, float rad) {
        float deg = rad * 180 / 3.1415927f;
        int r = Color.red(color);
        int g = Color.green(color);
        int b = Color.blue(color);

        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        ColorMatrix tmp = new ColorMatrix();

        cm.setRGB2YUV();
        tmp.setRotate(0, deg);
        cm.postConcat(tmp);
        tmp.setYUV2RGB();
        cm.postConcat(tmp);

        final float[] a = cm.getArray();

        int ir = floatToByte(a[0] * r +  a[1] * g +  a[2] * b);
        int ig = floatToByte(a[5] * r +  a[6] * g +  a[7] * b);
        int ib = floatToByte(a[10] * r + a[11] * g + a[12] * b);

        return Color.argb(Color.alpha(color), pinToByte(ir),
                          pinToByte(ig), pinToByte(ib));
    }

    private static final float PI = 3.1415926f;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX() - CENTER_X;
        float y = event.getY() - CENTER_Y;
        boolean inCenter = java.lang.Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) <= CENTER_RADIUS;

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mTrackingCenter = inCenter;
                if (inCenter) {
                    mHighlightCenter = true;
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mTrackingCenter) {
                    if (mHighlightCenter != inCenter) {
                        mHighlightCenter = inCenter;
                        invalidate();
                    }
                } else {
                    float angle = (float)java.lang.Math.atan2(y, x);
                    // need to turn angle [-PI ... PI] into unit [0....1]
                    float unit = angle/(2*PI);
                    if (unit < 0) {
                        unit += 1;
                    }
                    mCenterPaint.setColor(interpColor(mColors, unit));
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (mTrackingCenter) {
                    if (inCenter) {
                        mListener.colorChanged(mCenterPaint.getColor());
                    }
                    mTrackingCenter = false;    // so we draw w/o halo
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public ColorPickerDialog(Context context,
                         OnColorChangedListener listener,
                         int initialColor) {
    super(context);

    mListener = listener;
    mInitialColor = initialColor;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    OnColorChangedListener l = new OnColorChangedListener() {
        public void colorChanged(int color) {
            mListener.colorChanged(color);
            dismiss();
        }
    };

    setContentView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), l, mInitialColor));
    setTitle("Pick a Color");
}
}
```

You can choose erase from menu option to erase. You see part of the draw in erased

[image]

Comment: @koti that's bcoz you are using   mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                                PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

Comment: Is it possible to remove that black color

Comment: @koti chekc this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html. I don't think so. It's meant to work that way

Comment: @Raghunandan how to implement undo functionality in above code can you please guide me?

Comment: @DhavalKhant with the above not possible. you need to have list of points to draw. when you choose undo remove the last point from arraylist and call invalidate() to refresh the draw

Comment: @Raghunandan okay. I have done it in this way by storing path and paint but problem is when i draw in erase mode it will draw black line.this problem also solved by view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null) if api level >11; but what about api level<11?

Comment: @DhavalKhant i am not aware of it

Comment: @Koti an update why is it black https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54105#c1

Answer (score 0):

I am having a very similar problem.. Only for my drawing surface, the black of the eraser paint is always visible..  i want a result like the image above but not getting it..  How ever when i save my canvas out as a png, the erasing is correct.. but while drawing, you see every eraser you made as black even after touch_UP..  please see [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197435/trying-to-create-an-eraser-paint-for-canvas)